# Jacl script behaves wrongly in case of special characters \ ! ; $

Tags: bash, jacl

Hi I have written one jacl script which is not working properly in case of ; $ ! \

### test.jacl

```
set password [ lindex $argv 1 ]

puts "Hello your entered password is  $password"
```

### Script OUTPUT

When I run

```
../test.jacl testUser Foo\b4r*
```

it returns

```
Hello your entered password is Foob4r*
```

CASE 2:

```
 ../test.jacl testUser Foo$b4r*
```

OUTPUT

```
Hello your entered password is Foo*
```

CASE 3:

```
../test.jacl testUser Foo;b4r*
```

OUTPUT

```
Hello your entered password is Foo
```

CASE 3:

```
../test.jacl testUser Foo!b4r*
```

OUTPUT

```
-bash: !b4r*: event not found
```

Kindly suggest best way to overcome this problem

Comment: Quotes. Single quotes. They are your friends. The shell is seeing `$b4r` as a variable name and expanding it. The shell is seeing `;` as a command separator and splitting it. The shell is seeing `*` as a glob character and trying to expand it (that isn't happening here because nothing matches but it could). The shell is seeing `!` as a history expansion character and trying to expand it. All of those are prevented by single quoting the argument. (The `\\` too.)

Comment: The `!` is a special character inside bash - make sure the string is inside quotes.

Comment: @cdarke thanks for ur suggestion but here is some problem with single qoutes if we use ../test.jacl testUser 'Foo\b4r*' then it rturns output as Fo4r* so \b is being considered as backspace.

Comment: Then double the backslash.

Comment: Is this in bash or jacl?  You have tagged both products and its not clear which one you are having issues with.  In bash the single quotes prevent any interpolation.  I don't know jacl, but does it have raw strings marked with `{` `}` as in TCL?

Comment: @cdarke actually it is a jacl script which we are running from linux using wsadmin.sh

Comment: Did you try `{ }` raw strings?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have tried by passing passwod inside single quotes but what about if your password itself contains ' single quotes in that case it is failing example password=Test'pass\0rd'123

Comment: @cdarke I tried by enclosing password with {} but for some cases it is failing ex: {pass`word} {pass\word} {pass!word}

Comment: To embed single quotes inside a single quoted string you need to use `'\''` or `'"'"'` at each point you need the "inner" single quote. You don't have other options.